# SQL Server Agent Notification Email if a Step has an error, but the job is succesfull?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

Is it possible, that I can receive Email from Server Agent, if a step in an Agent has an error, but the Job is successful? In the history, I can see, that for example one Step has an Error, but all others were successful.

Comment: it was not possible to solve the Problem. If an error exists, the Job is ending. i want, that the Job runs all steps, for example from step 1 still step 6. If Step 3 has an error, i want have an email, that step 3 failed, but the whole Job must run succesfully.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve this with help of SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestEmailOnFail
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        /*
            Perform some action that might fail
        */
        SELECT 0/0; --THIS WILL FAIL
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @subject nvarchar(max) = 'Job Failure Notification';
        DECLARE @body nvarchar(max) = 'TestEmailOnFail Job Failed' 
            + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + 'Error Number:  ' + CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS nvarchar(max))
            + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + 'Error Message: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE();
        DECLARE @to nvarchar(max) = 'somebody@email.com';
        DECLARE @profile_name sysname = 'SQLMailProfileName';
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = @profile_name,
            @recipients = @to, @subject = @subject, @body = @body;
    END CATCH
END
```

You can refer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39128/sql-server-2008-how-to-send-an-email-when-a-step-in-a-sql-server-agent-job-fail) how it is being used.

Adding@ You can recieve email if Database mail is configured in very first place. On how to set that up read [How to Set Up Database Mail for SQL Server Job Failures](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/desiree/how-to-set-up-database-mail-for-sql-server-job-failures/)

Also, In SQL Agent Job Properties-> step > edit> Advanced --you can also check Include step output in history to get the message from step failure.

Leave the On failure action to Quit the job reporting failure.